# PHP bindParam with mysql function

Tags: php, mysqli, timestamp, bindparam

Is it possible to use OOP of PHP where I could `bind_param` with mysql build-in functions?

I have a following code which gives me an error of:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function FROM_UNIXTIME() in...
```

And the code is:

```
$sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (value1, value2, value3)
                             VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

$sql->bind_param('sss', $value1, $value2, FROM_UNIXTIME(" . $value3) . "));
$db -> query($sql, $connection);
```

As far as I understand from the error PHP does not offer FROM_UNIXTIME() method therefore my problem is that `bind_param` compiles string from my query into some-kin-of code which then is sent to mysql db. As where I could sent `FROM_UNIXTIME` as a string in a query then mysql would understand that method and act accordingly.

Anyway how can I run such a query with `bind_param`? I tried to convert my date-time to timestamp and put the output into the query but mysql shows only zeros in the table.

Comment: `VALUES (?, ?, FROM_UNIXTIME(?))`

Comment: Can you post it as answer because it works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use placeholders as arguments of mysql-functions - do it:

```
$sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (value1, value2, value3) VALUES (?, ?, FROM_UNIXTIME(?))");
$sql->bind_param('sss', $value1, $value2, $value3);
```